# How to set a default page in Reporting Server so that a user can land on a certain page with specified filters every time they open a report file?

Tags: powerbi

I am creating PBI reports with multiple pages. My client requirement is that when a user opens a report they should land on a certain page with specified filters. How to achieve such behaviour in Power BI, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a featured dashboard by using "Set as featured" feature. You can make the report page as set as featured. Hope it helps!

Comment: HI, Thank you for your response. I understand that feature works in Power BI Service to land on a specific dashboard. But my requirement is to land on a report page with specific filters on.

Comment: How is your client using/ sharing the report? Usually most organizations will have a Power BI service and dashboard where the reports will be shared. I wished I was of more help but in case you find a solution or work around or any other alternative then please share it here. It would be interesting to know. Thanks.